# How do I search for a specific field in a csv file then print the entire row in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I would include my whole program but it is too long so I will provide an example:

Say I had this csv file:

```
John, 23, 1944, Africa
Fred, 45, 1922, China
Bob, 23, 1999, Japan
```

How do I search the file and print the row that 1944 is specifically in?
Essentially what I want it to do is find 1944, then print the whole row 1944 is in.

Also, if it's structured like

```
Name, Age, Year, Nation
John, 23, 1944, Africa
Fred, 45, 1922, China
Bob, 23, 1999, Japan
```

How would you print the found row plus the top row as well?

Many thanks.

Edit:
Why is down voting necessary? I legitimately cannot find any information on this. Therefore I have to ask.

Comment: Python has a `csv` module for parsing CSV files.  The documentation includes examples, and there are lots of examples of that module online (including elsewhere here on SO).  Show us what you've tried so far, and let us know where the documentation was unclear or where you don't understand the behavior of your code.

Comment: I have searched for what I am trying to do with absolutely no success. From what I understand, I have no idea how to do it. I am currently using the csv module successfully, for example my program can append the list given inputs, find given x,y coordinates, but I don't know how to make it search for a user inputed value and then print that whole row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This program answers your first question:

```
import csv
import sys

with open('csv1.txt') as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp, skipinitialspace=True)
    writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
    writer.writerows(row for row in reader if row[2] == '1944')
```

And this answers your second question:

```
import csv
import sys

with open('csv2.txt') as fp:
    top_row = next(fp)
    sys.stdout.write(top_row)
    reader = csv.reader(fp, skipinitialspace=True)
    writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
    writer.writerows(row for row in reader if row[2] == '1944')
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does skipinitialspace, and sys.stdout do, in simpler terms?

Comment: The first [ignores "whitespace immediately following the delimiter"](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.skipinitialspace), while the second ["corresponds to the interpreter’s standard output stream"](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sys.html#sys.stdin).

Comment: Hi Rob, I am trying my best to make this work, however there does not seem to by any output to print using this. Furthermore, why are you using the writer function if all I want to do is search for it and print the row, not alter anything? I'm a bit confused, sorry.

Comment: I'm using the writer function to print the row. The code doesn't alter the disk file at all.

Comment: Oh okay, it is now working. Only problem is that it prints the top row, but not the row where '1944' is found?

Comment: Then it didn't find '1944'. Perhaps the input you are using differs in some significant way from the input in your question. Try switching to a `for` loop and printing out each row: `for row in reader: print row` and see what the output is.

Comment: I am in fact using a different input. I am searching for a user input variable called OCLC with a value of whatever the user enters, for example OCLC = 12345. Theoretically my program would search the csv for whatever the user has entered, and if it finds a matching number, it should print the entire row where that number is. The only thing I have changed with your suggested code is changing == '1944' to == OCLC. Would this cause a problem?

Comment: Sure, if `OCLC` has some value other than `'1944'`. For example, it could be `'1944\n'` or `' 1944'` or even the integer `1944`. It all depends upon how you created the `OCLC` variable.

Comment: Yes but I have adjusted it so it looks for whatever is contained in OCLC, not '1944' itself. OCLC will always be an integer, is there any way to fix this?

Comment: `row[2]` will always be a string. You say that `OCLC` will always be an integer, so they will never compare as equal. (To see what I mean, try `print (1944 == '1944')` in an interactive Python session.) You'll want to coerce one of them to be the type of the other. There many "ways to fix this"; the correct one depends upon the rest of your program. Two that might work are `if str(OCLC) == row[2]` and `if OCLC == int(row[2])`.

Comment: If you mean writing the last line like : writer.writerows(row for row in reader if str(OCLC) == row[2]), either way doesn't work, just prints the top row and nothing else.